# It / this / that

Tags: word-choice, pronouns

Which of the three options is the correct one? What I tried referring to through the pronoun is **having similar personalities.** Does the sentence appear clear with the use of the pronoun?

In a friendship it is very important to have similar personalities because **it / this / that** allows friends to be on the same wavelength. **It / This / That** also allows you to have smooth communication with them.

Comment: I could make a new post asking what this post is trying to ask

Comment: As far as I'm concerned you could use any of the 3 options in either instance with essentially the same meaning. They all work. Your choice.

Comment: The first sentence refers to _friends_ in general, the second suddenly refers to _you_ and _them_.